# Ion tabs rendering differently on desktop versus mobile

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework, sass

I've recently styled my `ion-tabs`.

They seem to be rendering correctly on desktop but not on mobile.

What am I doing wrong?

**On desktop:**

[image]

`ion-tabs` views correctly.

**On mobile:**

[image]

`ion-tabs` goes white.

What do I need to do to get both looking the same. I have been looking at [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/tabs-not-showing-the-same-style-in-desktop-browser-and-android/6650/5), and apparently I need to make a custom theme, but was wondering if there was a quicker approach.

This is my code so far:

**html**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Home Tab -->
  <ion-tab icon-off="ion-android-home" icon-on="ion-android-home" ui-sref="tab.home">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Notifications Tab -->
  <ion-tab icon-off="ion-android-notifications" icon-on="ion-android-notifications" ui-sref="tab.notifications">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-notifications"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Search Tab -->
  <ion-tab icon-off="ion-android-search" icon-on="ion-android-search" ui-sref="tab.search">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-search"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab icon-off="ion-android-person" icon-on="ion-android-person" ui-sref="tab.account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

**scss**

```
// Tabs

.tabs {
    background-color: #242424;
}

ion-tabs.tabs-color-active-positive .tab-item {
    color: #fff !important;
}

.tab-item .icon {
    padding-top: 2px;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ionic.css file which has the class definition for `ionicons` are not getting included in `index.html` as part of the mobile build.

Make sure that:

1. the index.html file at `platforms/www/<android/ios>/<path to index.html>` contains reference to ionic.css
2. The file `ionic.css` is copied at the required path

You can also inspect your mobile build in `chrome://inspect` for android or using safari for ios builds to make sure that this file is available in the mobile build of your app